# Custom Slider - Looking For Guidance For Additional Feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

New to Javascript and got some help here from a previous thread but wanted to expand on what I already created. The live site can be seen at **[www.cpointweb.com/dtv/](http://www.cpointweb.com/dtv/)**

I am wanting to highlight the blue box on the right, for whichever active slider it is on. I realize I can achieve this with .addClass() however I can't wrap my head around how that works with there being a different id for each slider...

With there being different ID's, how would the loop know of which id to change the class? I feel like if I apply it within the mouseover, it will only work when I hover over it with the mouse? or am I just thinking about this wrong?

I assume this is something far more simple than I am making it, but I am at a loss and thought I could ask for help!

```
            var dataArray = [[1,"Dossani Turnage & Van Hoose Thanks You!", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum", "img/slider-one.jpg"], [2, "With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum", "img/slider-two.jpg"], [3,"With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum", "img/slider-three.jpg"],[4,"With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum", "img/slider-four.jpg"],[5,"With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum", "img/slider-five.jpg"],[6,"With Dossani, Turnage & Van Hoose...", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum", "img/slider-6.jpg"]];

            var loopTime = 5000;
            var count = 1;

            $(function(){
                SetTimeout(Loop, loopTime);
            });


            function Loop(){
                changeSlider(dataArray[count][0], dataArray[count][1], dataArray[count][2], dataArray[count][3]);
                count++;
                if(count >= dataArray.length) count = 0;
                setTimeout(Loop, loopTime);


            }

            function changeSlider(id, header, html, img) {
                var rightHtml = '<h2>' + header + '</h2><p>' + html + '</p>';
                var slider = '<img src="' + img + '" />';

                $('.right').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).html(rightHtml).fadeIn('slow');

                });
                $('.slider-image').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $(this).html(slider).fadeIn('slow');

                });

            }

            $('#1').mouseover(function() {
                var id = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
                changeSlider(dataArray[id][0], dataArray[id][1], dataArray[id][2], dataArray[id][3]);
            });


            $('#2').mouseover(function() {
                var id = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
                changeSlider(dataArray[id][0], dataArray[id][1], dataArray[id][2], dataArray[id][3]);
            });

            $('#3').mouseover(function() {
                var id = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
                changeSlider(dataArray[id][0], dataArray[id][1], dataArray[id][2], dataArray[id][3]);

            });

            $('#4').mouseover(function() {
                var id = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
                changeSlider(dataArray[id][0], dataArray[id][1], dataArray[id][2], dataArray[id][3]);

            });

            $('#5').mouseover(function() {
                var id = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
                changeSlider(dataArray[id][0], dataArray[id][1], dataArray[id][2], dataArray[id][3]);

            });

            $('#6').mouseover(function() {
                var id = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
                changeSlider(dataArray[id][0], dataArray[id][1], dataArray[id][2], dataArray[id][3]);

            });
```

Comment: I know we can't see your HTML here, but I'm nervous about why you have IDs that are just "1, 2" etc. Do these objects have anything in common that would allow you to just mass-select, and iterate over, them? If not, could you add something?

Comment: Katana, are you referencing the dataArray? If so, I initially did that to try to solve my original problem, of changing the class of which slider was active, I tried it with an if/else statement but just haven't removed that yet.

Comment: I was mainly referring to the use of a `$('#1')` selector, but maybe that's the same temporary code.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this code inside your changeSlider function like so:

```
function changeSlider(id, header, html, img) {
    var rightHtml = '<h2>' + header + '</h2><p>' + html + '</p>';
    var slider = '<img src="' + img + '" />';

    //THIS IS THE NEW CODE
    $(".box").find("li").removeClass("yourclassname");
    $(".box").find("#" + id).addClass("yourclassname");


    $('.right').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).html(rightHtml).fadeIn('slow');

    });
    $('.slider-image').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).html(slider).fadeIn('slow');

    });

}
```

Comment: Ahh!! I have not read about find(); yet.

Thanks a lot for that. 

How hard would it be with my current code, to stop the loop when one of the boxes is hovered? Or is it altering quite a bit?

Comment: I provided another answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you would probably need to redo your code a bit. Something like this:

```
var loopTime = 1000;
var count = 0;
var timer = 0;

$(function() {
    Loop();
});

function stopTimer() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }
}

function startTimer() {
    timer = setTimeout(Loop, loopTime);
}

function Loop() {
    changeSlider(dataArray[count][0], dataArray[count][1], dataArray[count][2], dataArray[count][3]);
    count++;
    if (count >= dataArray.length)
        count = 0;
    startTimer();
}

function changeSlider(id, header, html, img) {
    var rightHtml = '<h2>' + header + '</h2><p>' + html + '</p>';
    var slider = '<img src="' + img + '" />';

    $(".box").find("li").removeClass("yourclassname");
    $(".box").find("#" + id).addClass("yourclassname");

    $('.right').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).html(rightHtml).fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('.slider-image').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).html(slider).fadeIn('slow');
    });
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    $('#' + i)
            .mouseenter(function() {
                var id = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
                count = id + 1;
                changeSlider(dataArray[id][0], dataArray[id][1], dataArray[id][2], dataArray[id][3]);
                stopTimer();
            })
            .mouseleave(function() {
                startTimer();
            });
}
```

Comment: I've implemented the code you provided and it can be seen at the same URL. It no longer loops through the 6 different sliders, seems to skip one and I am just curious as to why?

I'm working through your code as well to try to solve it myself, but am just providing some initial results from your last answer, which I appreciate!

Comment: mm i see.. thats weird.. there must be something wrong. Ill double check the code.

Comment: ok I checked, fixed, and edited the code above. Test it again. There were a few mistakes